# Firebase Function to Upload to GCP storage bucket Access Denied

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm doing a course on firebase functions and the function below copies the image uploaded to the firebase storage to GCP storage bucket.

Everything works fine for the instructor but I get the error:

> uploadToVCMBucket
> Error: fbpipeline-9876@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object. at new ApiError (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:73:15)

The instructor did not mention to setup permissions to gain access to the GCP bucket. Are there any steps we need to perform to grant the google function to copy to the GCP storage?

**Steps Followed:**

1. Setup Firestore, realtimedb and Storage
2. Upload image to firebase storage using react-firebase-file-uploader.
3. In GCP created a bucket as shown in the screenshot below
4. Deployed below function to firebase function to copy image from firebase storage to GCP Bucket

```
//Project setup

//Automl information
const project_name = 'ml-imageclassifier'
const project_region = 'us-central1'
const dataset_id = 'ICN10548w25656579083008'

const bucket_prefix = 'animals'
const labels = ['dog', 'cat', 'other']

const model_name = `${bucket_prefix}_${new Date().getTime()}`
const num_labels = labels.length;
const img_threshold = 10;


//Dependencies

const fs = require('fs')
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const automl = require('@google-cloud/automl')
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

firebase.initializeApp();

const database = firebase.database();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const storage = new Storage();


//helper function that taken in a path of the last image

function writeToDB (path) {
    console.log(path)
    database.ref(path).transaction(function(labelCount) {
        return labelCount + 1
    })
}


//whenever a image is uploaded to the storage bucket trigger the below to copy the image to GCP storage

exports.uploadToVCMBucket = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(event => {
    const file = storage.bucket(event.bucket).file(event.name)
    const newLocation = `gs://${project_name}-vcm/${event.name}`


    return file.copy(newLocation)
        .then((err, copiedFile, resp) => {
            return event.name.substring(0, event.name.lastIndexOf('/'))
        }).then((label) => {
            return writeToDB(label)
        });

})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to grant the creator object to you service account you can use the following command in the cloud shell:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceaccount:YOURSERVICEACCOUNT:objectCreator gs://YOURBUCKET
```

And to check if the command works you can use the following command to check if the service account have the correct role:

```
gsutil iam get gs://YOUTBUCKET
```